# Need help writing algorithm in Python/Sage

Tags: python, algorithm, sage

I'm a complete novice to python and sage so I need some help and clarification on the steps all the way through. This is a question concerning game theory.

First I will describe the algorithm and then I will propose a solution the best I can.

The algorithm:

> I want to start the program with a random variable from 1-100. This
>   variable will be defined 'S'. I also want to define a set of variables
>   'C' which can be deducted from S every turn, this set is {1,2,3,4,5,6}
>   (in other words the user and computer can deduct 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6
>   from S. If variable S is divisible by 7 (e.g. 21), then print: "I
>   lose". If not, the game can begin.
>
> Let's say that the random variable turns out to be 20. The player is
>   now prompted to enter a number within the range of C. When the player
>   has entered the number, I want the program to deduct that number from
>   S, so if the player enters 4 (a legal move), S is then 20-4=16. The
>   computer then calculates mod(S,7) and finds out that modulo 16,7 is 2
>   so it deducts 2 from S, in other words, 16-2=14.
>   If the player enters a number which results in S being divisible by 7, such as 6 (20-6=14) then the computer simply deducts 1 and attempts to get to such a number again next round.
>
> The game continues until the computer eventually wins as the player is
>   eventually placed at 7 and has to deduct a number which the computer
>   can finish with (user deducts 6, computer deducts the last one and
>   wins). Print: "I win".

So like I said, I have literally no experience in python and sage so I can only go by my (limited) java experience:

I would attempt to establish a variable S with some 'ran' element (no idea what it's called in python). I would then attempt something like:

```
if S%7=0 then print "I lose"

else

prompt "Pick a number between 1 and 6, those included".

Declare user input as variable U.

Do S-U=S

Now do S-S%7=S
```

Now I want the program to realize when `S=7` and then print: "You lose". If you can help me go all the way, though, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

def playgame():
    s = random.randint(1,100) #grabs a random integer between 1 and 100
    POSS = range(1,7) #range ignores the last number, so this is [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    if not s % 7: #if s%7 != 0
        print("I lose")
        return #exit the function
    while s > 0: #while s is still positive
        choice = 0 #set choice to 0 (this may as well have been "foo",
                   #                 I just needed it to not be in POSS)
        while choice not in POSS: #until the user picks a valid number
            choice = int(input("Select a number between 1 and 6: ")) #prompt for input
        s -= choice #subtract choice from s, then set the difference to s
        print("You subtracted {}, leaving {}".format(choice,s)) #print for the user
        comp_choice = s%7 #the computer's choice is always s%7
        s -= comp_choice #subtract the comp's choice from s, then set the diff to s
        print("I subtracted {}, leaving {}".format(comp_choice,s)) #print for user
    print("I win!") #since we know computer will always win, I don't have to do a check

playgame() #run the function
```

Here's a vastly more complicated function that does essentially the exact same thing ;-)

```
class Entity(object):
    """Base class that should not be instantiated on its own -- only
       exists to be inherited from. Use Player() and Computer() instead"""
    def __init__(self,name=None):
        if name is None:
            name = input("What's your name? ")
        self.name = name
        self.myturn = False
    def __str__(self):
        # this magic function means calling str(self) returns str(self.name)
        # included so I can do print(player)
        return self.name

    def makemove(self,choice):
        """finds the global s and subtracts a given choice from it,
           printing the choice and the result to the user."""
        global s
        s -= choice
        print("{} chooses {}, leaving {}".format(self,choice,s))
        return choice
    def activate(self):
        self.myturn = True
        return self
    def deactivate(self):
        """does exactly self.myturn = False"""
        self.myturn = False

class Player(Entity):
    """A player-controlled Entity"""
    def getchoice(self):
        """Prompts the user for a choice, ensuring it's between 1 and 6, then
           calls Entity's makemove() with that as an argument"""
        choice = None
        while choice not in range(1,7):
            choice = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 6: "))
        return super().makemove(choice)

class Computer(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="Computer Player")
        #overrides to ensure every Computer object has the name Computer Player

    def getchoice(self):
        """grabs a number for the computer, and makes its move"""
        global s
        choice = s%7
        if choice == 0: #edge case where computer goes first on an s where s%7==0
            choice = random.randint(1,6)
        return super().makemove(choice)

class Game(object):
    """Class defining an instance of the Game

FUNCTIONS:
 Game.start() <-- use this to start the game"""

    def __init__(self,playerArray=[]):
        """defines s as a global, ensures the players array is built
           correctly, and gives s a random int value between 1-100"""
        global s
        if type(playerArray) is Player:
            playerArray = [playerArray]
        while len(playerArray) < 2:
            playerArray.append(Computer())
        self.players = playerArray
        s = random.randint(1,100)

    def start(self):
        """Let's play!"""

        global s
        print ("""
====================================
 THE GAME BEGINS NOW!!!
 We will begin with a value of: {:3}
====================================""".format(s).lstrip())
        turn = random.randint(1,len(self.players))-1

        while True:
            try:active_player = self.players[turn].activate()
            except IndexError: print(turn)
            choice = active_player.getchoice()
            if s <= 0: break
            active_player.deactivate() # is active_player.myturn = False
            turn += 1
            if turn == len(self.players): turn = 0 #wrap the list
        for player in self.players:
            #this will execute the turn s becomes zero
            if player.myturn:
                winner = player
                break
        print("Winner: {}".format(winner))

import random

game = Game()
game.start()
```

Comment: This looks good, but I get an error:  File "main.py", line 12
    choice = int(input("Select a number between 1 and 6: "))
                                                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

I'm trying to run it at http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php

I'd like to see it run before I start messing with it.

Comment: Looks like PythonWin mixed tabs with spaces when I copied without prompts. I've changed it now.

Comment: Though if you're trying to run it online, that almost certainly will fail when it prompts the user for input. When I ran it through that utility you linked, it gave me an EOFError when then script asked for user input.

Comment: It works perfectly now! I'm going to analyze the code and learn from it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3200098 I commented my code describing each line. I'll write you something a bit more complex, if you want to learn more about Python.

Comment: Thanks. I added to your code:     if s % 7 == 0:
        comp_choice = 1
    else:
        comp_choice = s%7

The code runs fine but the computer doesn't choose anymore. I can't seem to notice what's wrong with my code.

The problem was that if the user selected a number which resulted in S being divisible by 7, the computer would deduct 0 (which is an illegal move).

Comment: sorry, the problem was just some indentation (which I have now learned about Python!)

Comment: @user3200098 I added an example using OOP, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

```
S=random.randint(1,100) #will pick a random number

user_input = int(raw_input("Enter a number:")) #will get an integer from the user

#subtraction and modulo work just like in any other language ...

if(condition):
    do_something() #is the format for if statements
```

does that cover all your questions? or did I miss some?